# system.applicationHost entry in Azure Log Stream

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics, azure-configuration

I have an App Service which is happily running on Azure and everything works fine however when I view the Log Stream I have the following entries after Application Logs gets connected:

[image]

As you can see in above logs I get

```
2017-07-28T10:42:42 :(6,10), No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='~1xxx']/application[@path='/websitelogs']'
```

This obviously is complaining about the [system.application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/) which I do not have in my web.config.

1. Should I care about this message?
2. How would I get rid of this message in Azure Log stream?
3. Since system.applicationHost contains global configuration settings that are used by the Windows Process Activation Service in IIS, if I hypothetically speaking add a new section like the one in [system.applicationHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/)

[image]

above configuration gets propagated to all sites on my azure server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply ignore this. :-)

So the message is simply an indication that you have the **Azure Web Site Log Browser** [Site Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-web-sites-extensions/) installed. The path `/websitelogs` corresponds to **Azure Web Site Log Browser** site extension.

If you notice, it is performing a sequence of operations, where it

- It checks whether there is an entry for the path `/websitelogs`
- As it is not found, it proceeds with **Insert** operation and creates an application type.

This will be done for any **Site Extensions** that you have installed.

At the end, if you check the applicationhost.config file, you will see an entry similar to this:

```
<sites>
 <site name="~1samplewebapp" id="80239797">
    <application path="/websitelogs" preloadEnabled="true" applicationPool="~1kaushalp">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\home\SiteExtensions\websitelogs" />
    </application>
  </site>
</sites>
```

You will find the Transformation logs here: **`D:\home\LogFiles\Transform`**

Here is a snippet of the same activity from my logs:

```
2017-07-28T16:41:41 Start 'websitelogs' site extension transform
2017-07-28T16:41:41 :(6,10), No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='~1samplewebapp']/application[@path='/websitelogs']'
2017-07-28T16:41:41 Not executing Remove (transform line 6, 68)
2017-07-28T16:41:41 StartSection Executing Insert (transform line 7, 64)
2017-07-28T16:41:41 on /configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='~1samplewebapp']/application
2017-07-28T16:41:41 Applying to 'site' element (no source line info)
2017-07-28T16:41:41 Inserted 'application' element
2017-07-28T16:41:41 EndSection Done executing Insert
2017-07-28T16:41:41 Successful 'D:\home\SiteExtensions\websitelogs\applicationHost.xdt' site extension transform
```

Here is a screenshot of what this looks like

[image: WebSiteLogs Site Extension]